# Table containing lists

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a question. If one would like to create a 3 by 3 table in which each object is a character list container. how would I proceed ?

I tried using double pointers but then I can't push my lists in the matrix.
With a triple pointer I'm completely lost...I tried this;

```
char ***obj;
obj = new char **[3]; 
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        obj[i] = new char*[3];}
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            obj[i][j] = new char;}
```

BUT now when I call for one of the element of obj it outputs not only the list corresponding to the index, but also all of the ones following...I'd really appreciate some clarifications !

Comment: *If one would like to create a 3 by 3 table in which each object is a character list container.* - `std::array<std::list<T>, 3*3>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::array` instead of the pointers from Hades.

```
#include <array>
#include <list>

typedef std::array<std::array<std::list<char>,3>,3> ArrayList;

int main()
{
  ArrayList myList;  
  myList[0][0].push_back('a'); // add the letter 'a' to the list located at (0,0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for that. I was doing bad. calling a table inside a class solves my problem without having to use to much advanced features. cheers

```
class Produits
{
    private:
    char *nom;
    Produits *tableau[3];
    public:
    Produits(){      
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            tableau[i] = tableau[3];}}
    int Affichage(int A, int B){
        printf("%s", tableau[A][B].nom);}
};
```